# Remove white space and shrinking

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm new to coding and hope you guys can help me with this two problems

1. I've been trying to remove a huge white space that appeared in the bottom of my anchors, which I found out from where the problem originates and tried everything but the space only disappeared by removing those anchors (Right side - css: R-news)
2. It's been bugging me that every time I change the size of the window on my browser the website shrinks and I can't find the reason for it even though I don't have the "viewport meta tag" in html nor the @viewport in css, you'll notice the changes once you change the size of the window in fiddle

Q: Why does IE adds a white/black border to the images?

Thank you in advance

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="Images/home.png" width="360" height="360" alt="home-icon" id="home"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">1B</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">2B</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">3B</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">4B</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">5B
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gr84a/)

Comment: You don't have a closing anchor tag for ` <a href="#">5B`.

Comment: I have it but apparently I erased it while pasting the markup on here

Answer (score 0):

if you use HTML 5 you do not need to use

```
`<div>`
```

with HTML 5 try

```
    <nav class="somthing">

    <ul>
        <li>
            text
         </li>
    </ul>

   </nav>
```

it may help with the space problem you are having with IE, problem will still ha[en with IE 6 though ....

Comment: Thanks for the advice but nothing happened after I changed the "div" tag and I'm not really focusing my website on IE since not a lot of people use it but is always good to have your website working perfectly in every browser